# How to run a bash script in terminal but hide the terminal on startup?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, startup, scripts, cuttlefish

I have a backup script on start up with cuttlefish. I set it on "Run in terminal" but I want to hide the terminal on start up. I also have the terminal in the start up applications. How do I hide the back up terminals (2) but keep my "main" terminal still visible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you you select the script as executable and uncheck the "run in terminal", then cuttlefish will run the script without displaying it in a terminal

Of course the script has to be executable (enter `chmod u+x /path/to/your/script.sh` in your terminal) and must provide a shebang (the first line in the script should be something like `#!/bin/bash`).